# Multi-Seat with Kubuntu 17.10 / Artful (systemd, sddm, KDE)

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, udev

I want to set up multi-seat on my PC. I already added a second VGA adapter to make things easier/possible?.

We have got:

- Kubuntu Artful 17.10 (KDE)
- systemd
- sddm (we probably have to use lightdm, as sddm lacks multi-seat features)
- Intel i5-4570S on-die gfx
- really old ATI RV710/Radeon HD4350/4550

Let us try to document a generic solution for recent Kubuntu/Ubuntu versions.

**I am stuck that if I start X I don't have any input on `seat0` and random noise on `seat-tv`.**

*I created a new question because those existing questions/answers are either specialized in hardware or incomplete in explaining background. At least I wasn't able to solve the problem using existing sources.*

*I created a community answer, so feel free to edit the answer below.*

When finished I might add how to start Kodi only without display-manager and window-manager on seat-tv.

Comment: I found another solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/wayland/comments/b9ztpc/multiseat_wayland_kde_plasma_without_display/

Answer (score 0):

## Before starting

- Backup your system and/or etc
- Install `openssh-server` and make sure you can login from another PC in case your local login doesn't work
- disable automatic start of display manager: `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
- think about a good name for your seats. Conventions says it has to start with `seat-`. I choose `seat-tv`.

## Set-up udev rules

- read about udev rules here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch07s03.html http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html
- find your hardware by using one of these

  ```
  $ lspci -nn
  [stripped non-audio, nongraphics]
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
  00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
  00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550] [1002:954f]
  01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series] [1002:aa38]

  $ lsusb
  [stripped non-audio, non-input]
  Bus 003 Device 019: ID 413c:a503 Dell Computer Corp. [Soundbar]
  Bus 003 Device 018: ID 03f0:034a Hewlett-Packard Elite Keyboard
  Bus 003 Device 017: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
  Bus 003 Device 023: ID 1915:0196 Nordic Semiconductor ASA [Mele USB remote keyboard and mouse]
  # how do I get a more useful output from lsusb?

  $ loginctl seat-status
  Devices:
  ├─/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
  │ input:input1 "Power Button"
  ├─/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
  │ input:input5 "Video Bus"
  ├─/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
  │ input:input0 "Power Button"
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/renderD128
  │ drm:renderD128
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1
  │ [MASTER] drm:card1
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-DP-1
  │ │ [MASTER] drm:card1-DP-1
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-HDMI-A-1
  │ │ [MASTER] drm:card1-HDMI-A-1
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-HDMI-A-2
  │ │ [MASTER] drm:card1-HDMI-A-2
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-HDMI-A-3
  │ │ [MASTER] drm:card1-HDMI-A-3
  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-VGA-1
  │   [MASTER] drm:card1-VGA-1
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/renderD129
  │ drm:renderD129
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/graphics/fb1
  │ [MASTER] graphics:fb1 "inteldrmfb"
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0
  │ sound:card0 "HDMI_1"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input10
  │ │ input:input10 "HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input11
  │ │ input:input11 "HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input12
  │ │ input:input12 "HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input8
  │ │ input:input8 "HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input9
  │   input:input9 "HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3
  │ usb:usb3
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:1915:0196.0027/input/input47
  │ │ input:input47 "MELE RI"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1915:0196.0028/input/input48
  │ │ input:input48 "MELE RI"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:1915:0196.0029/input/input49
  │ │ input:input49 "MELE RI"
  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5
  │   usb:3-5
  │   ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.1/3-5.1:1.0/0003:046D:C050.0017/input/input34
  │   │ input:input34 "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"
  │   ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.2/3-5.2:1.0/0003:03F0:034A.0018/input/input35
  │   │ input:input35 "Chicony HP Elite USB Keyboard"
  │   ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.2/3-5.2:1.1/0003:03F0:034A.0019/input/input36
  │   │ input:input36 "Chicony HP Elite USB Keyboard"
  │   ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.0/sound/card3
  │   │ sound:card3 "SoundBar"
  │   └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.3/0003:413C:A503.001A/input/input37
  │     input:input37 "Dell Dell AC511 USB SoundBar"
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4
  │ usb:usb4
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
  │ usb:usb1
  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
  │   usb:1-1
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1
  │ sound:card1 "PCH"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input13
  │ │ input:input13 "HDA Intel PCH Front Mic"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
  │ │ input:input14 "HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input15
  │ │ input:input15 "HDA Intel PCH Line"
  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input16
  │ │ input:input16 "HDA Intel PCH Line Out"
  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input17
  │   input:input17 "HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone"
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
  │ usb:usb2
  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
  │   usb:2-1
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sr0
  │ block:sr0
  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0
  │ scsi_generic:sg0
  ├─/sys/devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input6
  │ input:input6 "Eee PC WMI hotkeys"
  ├─/sys/devices/virtual/misc/kvm
  │ misc:kvm
  └─/sys/devices/virtual/misc/rfkill
  misc:rfkill
  ```
- add rules by ...

  - using `loginctl` plus above pathes to create the udev rules, but I don't recommend it. *Do the bus IDs remain the same?*

    ```
    # gfx
    sudo loginctl attach seat-tv /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0
    sudo loginctl attach seat-tv /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/graphics/fb0
    # hdmi audio
    sudo loginctl attach seat-tv /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2
    # mele remote
    sudo loginctl attach seat-tv /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:1915:0196.0008/input/input21
    sudo loginctl attach seat-tv /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1915:0196.0009/input/input22
    sudo loginctl attach seat-tv /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:1915:0196.000A/input/input23
    ```
  - This adds rule files like the following. The rule sets ID_SEAT to seat-tv if ID_FOR_SEAT matches the given.

    ```
    $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/72-seat-graphics-pci-0000_01_00_0.rules`
    TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_FOR_SEAT}=="graphics-pci-0000_01_00_0", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-tv"
    ```
  - or creating the udev rules manually. *I prefer VendorID/ProductID for identification.* File names should start with 72 because other seat related stuff in `/lib/udev/rules.d` is 71 or 73.

    ```
    $ cat 72-seat0.rules
    # do I really need to set up anything for seat0?
    # It should just grab anything not allocated to another seat?
    # Intel GFX
    # if TAG contains seat and vendor and product match the hex codes than set ID_SEAT to seat0
    TAG=="seat", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x8086", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x0412", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0"

    # Dell AC511 Sound
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.0/sound/card3
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.3/0003:413C:A503.001A/input/input37
    TAG=="seat", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x413c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0xa503", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0"

    # HP Keyboard
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.2/3-5.2:1.0/0003:03F0:034A.0018/input/input35
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.2/3-5.2:1.1/0003:03F0:034A.0019/input/input36
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x03f0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x034a", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat0"

    # Logitech Mouse
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.1/3-5.1:1.0/0003:046D:C050.0017/input/input34
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0xc050", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat0"

    $ cat 72-seat-tv.rules
    # ATI RV710
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/graphics/fb0
    # any graphics card should already have the master-of-seat TAG,
    # see /lib/udev/rules.d/71-u-d-c-gpu-detection.rules
    #SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x1002", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x954f", TAG+="master-of-seat"
    TAG=="seat", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x1002", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x954f" , ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-tv"

    # ATI HDMI audio
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2
    #/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input7
    TAG=="seat", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x1002", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0xaa38", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-tv"
    #TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_FOR_SEAT}=="sound-pci-0000_01_00_1", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-tv"

    # Mele USB remote keyboard and mouse
    #1915:0196
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x1915", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x0196", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat-tv", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-tv"

    # TODO usb hub where all attached devices belong to this seat
    #SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat-tv"
    ```
- you should now (after display manager restart?) realize the following

  - the inputs assigned to other seats should not work any more on seat0
  - screens assigned to other seats should disappear from system settings/display
  - same for the audio device

## Set-Up Xorg

- create a dir like /etc/X11/xorg.conf.multiseat so it won't change your default set-up.
- fetch current xorg config with `sudo Xorg :2 -configure`
- create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.multiseat/90-seat-tv.conf`

  ```
  Section "Device"
          # get this from Xorg -configure
          Identifier  "Card0"
          Driver      "amdgpu"
          BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"

          MatchSeat      "seat-tv"
  #    Identifier     "Seat-TV"
  #    Option         "ProbeAllGpus" "FALSE"
  EndSection

  #Section "Device"
  #       Identifier  "Card1"
  #       Driver      "amdgpu"
  #       BusID       "PCI:1:0:1"
  #EndSection

  Section "InputClass"
          Identifier      "ignore_other_seats"
          Option          "Ignore" "yes"
  EndSection

  Section "InputClass"
          Identifier      "use_seat_devices"
          MatchTag        "input_seat-tv"
          Option          "Ignore" "no"
  EndSection
  ```
- I don't know about the commented entries.
- Do I need a similar file for seat0 or are the defaults ok?
- TODO: Server Layout

## Test

- logout from gui and shutdown your window manager using `sudo service sddm stop`
- start X on all your seats - one after the other - and see what happens. `startx -- -layout seat0 -config xorg.conf.multiseat`, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_multiseat

## Undo

- temporarily

  - enable your window manager again `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`
- permanently

  - delete your udev files `/etc/udev/rules.d/72-*`
  - delete your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.multseat` folder

## What now?

- What am I missing?
- How does the Server Layout work?
- Mele keyboard somehow is not attached to seat-tv?